# How to give DatePicker a minute interval in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

does anyone know how to give the minutes DatePicker an interval? I am trying to only display multiples of 15 (0, 15, 30, 45). Is this only yet possible by interfacing with UIKit?

I believe it's not using the `in: ...Date()` part, at least I couldn't think of a solution. Here is my snippet:

```
DatePicker(
                "",
                selection: $selectedDate,
                /*in: ...Date(),*/
                displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute
            )
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can do it in SwiftUI yet. The `PartialRangeThrough<Date>` type you have to provide doesn't support stepping over values (You need something like the [`StrideThrough`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stridethrough) type for that and `DatePicker` doesn't accept that). Only way I see this is possible is by using UIDatePicker. Hopefully Apple fixes this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to configure using `UIDatePicker.appearance` before SwiftUI `DatePicker` is created.

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

[image: demo]

Main part is:

```
UIDatePicker.appearance().minuteInterval = 15
```

[Complete code in here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestDatePickerMinuteInterval.swift)

Comment: Does this affect **all** date pickers in the app? I mean, do you have to *reset* the appearance if other date pickers are used with the default minute interval?

Comment: Yes, appearance changes affect all instances created *after*, so if you need other DatePickers to be configured differently the corresponding appearance should be re-configured before each in-advance.

Comment: I tried this code iOS 15.5 and is causing re-rendered in a loop (blocking the app)

Answer (score 0):

can be tried this way:

```
  struct DatePickerView: View {
    @Binding var dateSelected: Date
    var type: DatePickerComponents? = .date

    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("", selection: $dateSelected, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            .onAppear {
                if type == .hourAndMinute {
                    UIDatePicker.appearance().minuteInterval = 15
                } else {
                    UIDatePicker.appearance().minimumDate = dateSelected
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using two pickers, one for hour and one for minute, and then converting to Date() afterwards? It's not pretty but this gets part of the way there:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var hour = 1
    @State private var minute = 0

    let minutes = [0, 15, 30, 45]

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                Picker("Hour", selection: self.$hour) {
                    ForEach(1...12, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                }
                .labelIsHidden()
                .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width / 4)
                .clipped()

                Picker("Minutes", selection: self.$minute) {
                    ForEach(self.minutes, id: \.self) { minute in
                        Text(minute == 0 ? " : 0\(minute)" : " : \(minute)")
                    }
                }
                .labelIsHidden()
                .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width / 4)
                .clipped()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I should have mentioned that, I tried using two pickers. I wasn't aware of `.clipped()` though. Without one picker always overlaid the other.
What's the benefit of using the GeometryReader vs. UIScreen?

Comment: One advantage might be that GeometryReader is native to SwiftUI. I haven't experimented with it to see why, but I have read the UIScreen runs into problems on SplitView.